# Firefox local storage and cache questions

Tags: firefox, browser-cache

Where I can find the contents of local storage saved in Firefox? I have searched into the profile and appdata folder, but I couldn't find any reference to local storage.

Also, is there any way I can clean the browser cache but keep local storage saved data and/or pinned tabs?

Comment: See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_Application_Cache#Storage_location_and_clearing_the_offline_cache) page on the Mozilla MDN docs.

Answer (score 2):

Type into the address bar: `about:cache`.